# Android how to play small Audio files from URL quickly

Tags: android

im trying to make an app which is playing samll audio files from internel which will b 4 to 5 seconds long just. I am using Media Player but it take 3 to 4 seconds on loading for every track.is there any way which play audio quickly like dubsmash app ? 
i will be very thankful for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use Media Player like this

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(URL_OF_FILE);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

and for more details [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: as mention above i use Media player but it take time to load.

Comment: i thin thi might be your answer http://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class

Comment: thanks for comment but i already applied this methid it doesnt help me. it take time to load. i wanna play it as quickly as audio play on dubsmash.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer takes about only 50ms (2015, maybe up to 200ms max, may be as little as 10ms) to prepare a small media file without spinning up the video decoders. What you are experiencing is network delay. The correct thing to do is preload the files that you are playing next, so that when the first track completes, you can set the next player to start right the way either with MediaPlayer.setNext.... or MediaPlayer.OnCompleteListener to achieve the same result. If all files are local, you can just prepare ahead of time.

Comment: thanks for comment. in my case media player always taking 3 to 4 seconds to play next audio. i can not use onCompleteListener to set Next because user while decide which files should be play next from list. is there any way i buffer 8 to 10 audios or any way so that when user chose any files it play quickly.

Comment: You can download the files yourself and proxy it to MediaPlayer.